# Ayuda al crear un JSON con PHP7

Tags: json, php7

Estoy trabajando con FusionCharts (https://www.fusioncharts.com/) y PHP 7. Para crear las gráficas estadísticas, se recomienda usar JSON. Al principio, para agilizar el proceso, utilizaba el JSON guardado en una variable y los valores los ponía con variables así:

```
$estadisticaTRL = '{ "chart": { "caption": "Estadísticas TRL", "subCaption": "Cantidad de proyectos por TRL", "use3DLighting": "0", "showPercentValues": "1", "decimals": "2", "useDataPlotColorForLabels": "1", "theme": "fusion", "bgColor": "#353535" }, "data": [ { "label": "TRL 1", "value": "' . $mostrarUno . '" }, { "label": "TRL 2", "value": "' . $mostrarDos . '" }, { "label": "TRL 3", "value": "' . $mostrarTres . '" }, { "label": "TRL 4", "value": "' . $mostrarCuatro . '" }, { "label": "TRL 5", "value": "' . $mostrarCinco . '" }, { "label": "TRL 6", "value": "' . $mostrarSeis . '" }, { "label": "TRL 7", "value": "' . $mostrarSiete . '" }, { "label": "TRL 8", "value": "' . $mostrarOcho . '" }, { "label": "TRL 9", "value": "' . $mostrarNueve . '" } ] }';
```

Pero esto es demasiado estáticos y para seguir con otras estadísticas, quisiera hacer llamados más dinámicos a la base de datos, generando un JSON automáticamente.

Así es el ejemplo del [Chart](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/msstackedcolumn2d):

```
{
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Product-wise break-up of quarterly revenue in last year",
        "subcaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
        "xaxisname": "Quarter",
        "yaxisname": "Sales (In USD)",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "numbersuffix": "M",
        "theme": "fusion"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "category": [
                {
                    "label": "Q1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q2"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q3"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Q4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dataset": [
        {
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Processed Food",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "26"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "29"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "31"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "seriesname": "Un-Processed Food",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "21"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "39"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "41"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "seriesname": "Electronics",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "27"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "25"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "28"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "26"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "seriesname": "Apparels",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "15"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "18"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "16"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "seriesname": "Others",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "12"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "17"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "16"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "15"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Y yo quiero aprovechar ese modelo para hacer una estadística, pero me queda muy difícil hacer tantas consultas para llenar los campos que requiero. He intentado hacerlo de forma manual para aprender, según el [ejemplo](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/php/your-first-chart-using-php). Entonces, esto es lo que he logrado:

```
$arrChartConfig = array("chart" => array("caption" => "TRL y Categoría de Priorización", "subCaption" => "", "xAxisName" => "TRL", "yAxisName" => "Total Proyectos", "theme" => "fusion"), "categories" => array("category" => array("label" => "TRL 1", "label" => "TRL 2", "label" => "TRL 3", "label" => "TRL 4", "label" => "TRL 5", "label" => "TRL 6", "label" => "TRL 7", "label" => "TRL 8", "label" => "TRL 9")), "dataset" => array("dataset" => array("seriesname" => "Seguridad Alimentaria", "data" => array("value" => 1, "value" => 2, "value" => 3, "value" => 4, "value" => 5, "value" => 6, "value" => 7, "value" => 8, "value" => 9))));
```

Pero esto no me muestra la gráfica. me muestra el fondo vacío. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a "traducir" el ejemplo que puse a un arreglo en PHP para tener mejor guía de cómo se debe manejar?

Agradezco con anterioridad la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba realizando un

```
echo json_encode($arrChartConfig);
```